# Matlab: Comparing two signals with different time values and placed impulses

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

We are analysing some signals that contains an impuls in the form of a dip in the standard signal in matlab.

[Signals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laYC8.png)

As you can see on the picture, we need to find the difference between the "Zlotty" and the "Krone". The two graphs besides each other, are the graphs that needs to be analyzed.

As you can see the time of the impulse is different in when it occures and in how long the impuls is. We can not use the Time as a value of measurements because that can vary randomly.

Each graph is made by vectors containing 2.5mio datapoints.

How would you use matlab to find a difference?

Comment: While motivating a non-standard approach to a problem is welcome, chit-chat (including salutations) is not. Please pay heed to [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks - I didn't think it had to be so formel. Is this better?

Comment: It is about considerate demand on (many a) readers' time rather than formality - including the emphasis on the title (speaking of which: 1) repeating the (first) tag seems redundant. 2) while I fail to come up with a better title, try if you can - `different time values` vs. _disparate time ranges_, `placed impulses` vs. `peculiarities at unlike positions in range`). I consider the 2nd revision markedly better. Here is something time-consuming to digest on first encounter: a [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @KennethKristiansenNielsen It doesn't have to be. Some users are overzealous.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the problem into two parts. Ensuring the same time scale for both signals and finding a possible time shift in the alignment of the resulting signals. The first part could be achieved by using the resample function of Matlab; and the second task by using cross-correlation. Using two nested for loops, you could perform a search for the "best" stretch factor and time shift that result in the maximum correlation coefficient.